# What is "Only not quite"

Tags: meaning, phrases, history

Context

Zimmermann dreamed of changing the world. And he would. Only not quite in the way he intended.

Comment: Normally "not quite" means "almost", but with a negative connotation.  In this case, however, the idiom "only not quite [in] the way ..." means that the stated action occurred but the outcome was somewhat different from what was expected.

Comment: Can you guess from the documentary?  Zimmerman wanted to distract the United States with a war with Mexico, which he tried to instigate.  When his plans became known, what did the documentary say about the US attitude toward the war in Europe?  Did the US enter the war?  How did that work out for Germany?  Do you think the result was what Zimmerman intended or wanted?

Comment: I suspect that the questioner understands 'not quite' completely.  He wants to know if 'only' adds anything.

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open in the hope that someone can explain lucidly Marr's use of irony. Is it true that Americans don't do Irony?

Answer (score 1):

> Zimmermann dreamed of changing the world. And he would. Only not quite in the way he intended.

Zimmermann would go on to realise his dream of changing the world, but **not in the exact manner in which he planned to do so.**

Here "*not quite*" should be interpreted as "*not exactly*".

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single phrase. 'Not quite' is a phrase. Only is just a qualifier . Together they mean the same as `though not quite`. 
So Zimmermann must have eventually succeeded in changing the world in some way which was different from what he intended.